# Performance Between Sql Server Computed Function and In Memory List

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have a question about the performance hit on 2 scenarios and which would be faster.

Option #1

Would it be faster to grab a list of all travel reports in memory and use C# to remove the ones that I dont want, ex:

```
var travelReports = db.TravelReports.Include("ApprovalStatuses")
            .Where(s => s.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
            travelReports.RemoveAll(s => s.Status == TravelReportStatus.Draft);
            travelReports.RemoveAll(s => s.Status == TravelReportStatus.NeedsInformation);
```

in which case the Status would be calculated on the model, using a NotMapped property and getter, using Approval Status like:

```
if (ApprovalStatuses.Count == 0)
{
    return TravelReportStatus.Draft;
}
else if (JobRoles.All(j => ApprovalStatuses.Any(a => a.Role == j && a.Status == ApprovalStatus.Approved)))
{
    return TravelReportStatus.Processed;
}
else if (ApprovalStatuses.Any(s => s.Status == ApprovalStatus.Denied))
{
    return TravelReportStatus.Denied;
}
else
{
    return TravelReportStatus.PendingApproval;
}
```

Option #2
Put a function on my Model in SQL and call the column Status:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTravelReportStatus(@travelReportId int)
RETURNS int
AS
-- Returns a Enum Int Value of the Status --
BEGIN

DECLARE @value int;
DECLARE @count int;
DECLARE @isReject int = 0;
SELECT @isReject = Count(*) FROM dbo.Approvals WHERE TravelReportId = @travelReportId and Status = 3;
SELECT @count = Count(*) FROM dbo.Approvals WHERE TravelReportId = @travelReportId;
SELECT @value =
CASE
WHEN @isReject > 0 THEN 3
WHEN @isReject = 0 and @count = 0 THEN 1
WHEN @isReject = 0 and @count > 0 and @count < 6 THEN 2
WHEN @isReject = 0 and @count >= 6 THEN 4
END;
return @value;
END;


Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.TravelReports ADD Status AS dbo.GetTravelReportStatus(Id)");
```

and then use SQL and entity framework to only get travel reports with the statuses I want Ex.

```
var travelReports = db.TravelReports.Include("ApprovalStatuses")
                .Where(s => s.Status == TravelReportStatus.PendingApproval || s.Status == TravelReportStatus.Processed || s.Status == TravelReportStatus.Denied)
                .Where(s => s.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
```

Travel reports will continuously grow but after around 4 years they will be moved to archive storage and no longer be in the database.

My question is will option 1 or option 2 provide me the best performance? And will option 2 hit the database with 2 queries every single time I request a Travel report? So If I returned a user 25 Travel Reports i'M going to hit the database 25^2 times to calculate the status, is there any way in codefirst EF to stop that?

Comment: "Would it be faster to grab a list of all travel reports in memory and use C# to remove the ones that I dont want?"  Not unless your table is *very* small.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry about the title, I will watch for that in the future :)

Comment: @KirkWoll in my example though isn't it actually going to hit the database 25^2 more times every time I use the TravelReports table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if EF is going to hit the database 3 times or not, but if it is the [`let`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) clause would resolve it so it would only hit it once.

```
var travelReports = (from s in db.TravelReports.Include("ApprovalStatuses")
                    let status = s.Status
                    where (status == TravelReportStatus.PendingApproval || 
                           status == TravelReportStatus.Processed || 
                           status == TravelReportStatus.Denied) && 
                           reports.IsDeleted == false
                    select reports).ToList();
```

Re-creating the `let` clause using the method syntax instead of the query syntax is much more difficult to do. You have to create a anonymous type to act as a container for your value. For this simple of a query it is not too hard but with more complex queries it may just be easier to use the query syntax.

```
var travelReports = db.TravelReports.Include("ApprovalStatuses")
                .Select(s => new {Query = s, Status = s.Status}) //Project to a new object that has the status pre-calculated
                .Where(s => s.Status == TravelReportStatus.PendingApproval || s.Status == TravelReportStatus.Processed || s.Status == TravelReportStatus.Denied)
                .Select(s => s.Query) //flatten the object back out.
                .Where(s => s.IsDeleted == false)
                .ToList();
```

---

P.S. To find out what query EF is going to generate just do `.ToString()` on the IQueryable object and it will return the SQL it will be sending to the server.

```
var travelReportsQuery = db.TravelReports.Include("ApprovalStatuses")
                .Where(s => s.Status == TravelReportStatus.PendingApproval || s.Status == TravelReportStatus.Processed || s.Status == TravelReportStatus.Denied)
                .Where(s => s.IsDeleted == false)

var travelReportsQueryText =  travelReportsQuery.ToString();
var travelReports = travelReportsQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks I will check the toString! When I asked about ef hitting the server extra times I mean about the calculated field on the table, and that function hitting a table 2 times. In order to use Status in a query like you have suggested though it needs to have the field in EF which I am still not sure would be the best performance wise.